# invoke python script and populate results on webpage

Tags: python, bash, server, web, webserver

I created a simple python script which takes a URL as input and once passed will do curl using multiple proxies and show the response code, now I want to create a webpage where others can use(my colleagues) as it will help them too, I want to create simple webpage which let them select set of proxy addresses, and input URL and upon submission, it will run the script on a machine(webserver) and populate the result to webpage using dynatable or datatable frameworks, but am not sure how or if it is possible as I didn't worked much in webserver thing, I want to know what tools I will need and how do I design it.

If python script can be called in terminal(as it needs to run curl) and show result on webpage based on output from script(which I will export to csv file), how can I do that? what to use xampp, wamp, lamp etc ?

Comment: You should add a tag JavaScipt

Answer (score 1):

You need a framework for this, something that will listen to your request coming from the front-end (webpage), there are tons out there as python framework, you can check [bottle framework](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) as a starting point.

So the flow would be something below.

```
1. from webpage, a request is sent to the backend
2. backend receive the request and run your logic (connecting to some server, computing logic, etc)
3. once backend process is done, backend then send the response to webpage
```

you can either use a REST approach or use templating functionality of the framework

Answer (score 0):

You will need a request. You can do this in JavaScript with an ajax request there are frameworks to hook it up straight to your python which allow you not to code the JavaScript https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp there are many JavaScript frameworks that will make this easier/ shorter to code.